# Try/Catch Underflow and Overflow Exceptions

Tags: c#

Need to utilize Underflow and Overflow exceptions using Try/Catch to pass the tests. There are series of tests that need to pass testing inputs that are outside of the bounds of the array.

Here is the code that is provided to me. I have to modify the SmartArray class. The Program class contains all the tests I need to pass.

```
using System;
```

namespace SmartArray_Test
{

```
class UnderflowException : Exception
{
    public UnderflowException(string s) : base(s) { }
}
class OverflowException : Exception
{
    public OverflowException(string s) : base(s) { }
}

class SmartArray
{
    int[] rgNums;

    public SmartArray()
    {
        rgNums = new int[5];
    }
    public SmartArray(int howMany)
    {
        rgNums = new int[howMany];
    }

    public void SetAtIndex(int idx, int val)
    {
        try
        {
            rgNums[idx]=val;
        }
        catch (UnderflowException Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
        }
        catch (OverflowException Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
        }
    }

    public int GetAtIndex(int idx)
    {
        try
        {
            return rgNums[idx];

        }
        catch (UnderflowException Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
        }
        catch (OverflowException Exception) 
        {    
            Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void PrintAllElements()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rgNums.Length; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(rgNums[i]);
    }

    public bool Find(int val)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rgNums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (rgNums[i] == val)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmartArray sa = new SmartArray();
        const int SMART_ARRAY_SIZE = 5;
        bool testPassed = false;

        Console.WriteLine("CHECK THIS: SmartArray starts with all zeros");
        sa.PrintAllElements();
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        try 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("================= SetAtIndex =================");
            Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Can add at slot 0?");
            sa.SetAtIndex(0, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to set element 0!");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNABLE TO SET ELEMENT 0!");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Can add at slots 0-4?");
        testPassed = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < SMART_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                sa.SetAtIndex(i, 10 * i);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNABLE TO SET ELEMENT {0}!", i);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                testPassed = false;
                break; // out of the loop
            }
        }
        if (testPassed)
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to set all elements!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to add at slot {0}?", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);

        try
        {
            sa.SetAtIndex(SMART_ARRAY_SIZE, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT {0} DID NOT OVERFLOW (but should have)", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to set element {0}!", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT {0} FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");


        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to add at slot {0}?", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE + 10);
        try 
        {
            sa.SetAtIndex(SMART_ARRAY_SIZE + 10, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT {0} DIDN'T OVERFLOW", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE + 10);
        }                  
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to set element {0}!", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT {0} FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to add at slot -1?");
        try 
        {
            sa.SetAtIndex(-1, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT -1 DIDN'T UNDERFLOW");
        }                  
        catch (UnderflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to set element -1!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT -1 FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to add at slot -10?");
        try
        {
            sa.SetAtIndex(-10, 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT -10 DIDN'T UNDERFLOW");
        }
        catch (UnderflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to set element -10!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: SET ELEMENT -10 FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("CHECK THIS: Should see 0, 10, 20, 30, 40");
        sa.PrintAllElements();
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("================= GetAtIndex =================");
        int valueGotten;
        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Can get from slot 0?");
        try
        {
            valueGotten = sa.GetAtIndex(0);
            if (valueGotten != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNEXPECTED VALUE FROM SLOT 0: (EXPECTED 0, GOT {0})", valueGotten);
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to get expected value from slot 0!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNABLE TO GET FROM SLOT 0");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Can get from slots 0-4?");
        testPassed = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < SMART_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                valueGotten = sa.GetAtIndex(i);
                if (valueGotten != 10 * i)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED:  UNEXPECTED VALUE AT SLOT {0} (EXPECTED {1}, GOT {2})", i, i * 10, valueGotten);
                    testPassed = false;
                    break; // out of the loop
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to get expected value from slot 0!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNABLE TO GET FROM SLOT {0}", i);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (testPassed)
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to get expected values!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to get from slot {0}?", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);
        try
        {
            valueGotten = sa.GetAtIndex(SMART_ARRAY_SIZE);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET FROM ELEMENT {0} DIDN'T OVERFLOW?", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE); 
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to get element at SMART_ARRAY_SIZE!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET ELEMENT AT SMART_ARRAY_SIZE FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to get from slot {0}?", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE + 10);
        try
        {
            valueGotten = sa.GetAtIndex(SMART_ARRAY_SIZE + 10);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET FROM ELEMENT {0} DIDN'T OVERFLOW?", SMART_ARRAY_SIZE + 10);
        }
        catch (OverflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to get element at SMART_ARRAY_SIZE!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET ELEMENT AT SMART_ARRAY_SIZE FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to get from slot -1?");
        try
        {
            valueGotten = sa.GetAtIndex(-1);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET FROM ELEMENT -1 DIDN'T UNDERFLOW");
        }
        catch (UnderflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to get element at -1!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET ELEMENT AT -1 FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to get from slot -10?");
        try
        {
            valueGotten = sa.GetAtIndex(-10);
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET FROM ELEMENT -10 DIDN'T UNDERFLOW");
        }
        catch (UnderflowException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to get element at -10!");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: GET ELEMENT AT -10 FAILED, BUT FOR THE WRONG REASON");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("================= Find =================");
        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Can find 0?");
        if (!sa.Find(0))
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNABLE TO FIND VALUE 0!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to find value 0!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Can find the values in slots 0-4?");
        testPassed = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < SMART_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                valueGotten = sa.GetAtIndex(i);
                if (!sa.Find(valueGotten)) // test by getting from array
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNABLE TO FIND {0}!", valueGotten);
                    testPassed = false;
                    break; // out of the loop
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: FIND (iteration " + i + ") FAILED BECAUSE GETATINDEX FAILED");
            }
        }
        if (testPassed)
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to find values that are already in the array!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Can find the values calculated to be in slots 0-4?");
        testPassed = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < SMART_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (!sa.Find(i * 10)) // test by re-calculating the result
            {
                Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: UNABLE TO FIND {0}!", i * 10);
                testPassed = false;
                break; // out of the loop
            }
        }
        if (testPassed)
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Able to find values calculated to be in the array!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to find -1?");
        if (sa.Find(-1))
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: ABLE TO FIND -1, WHICH SHOULD NOT BE PRESENT");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to find nonexistent value -1!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to find -10?");
        if (sa.Find(-10))
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: ABLE TO FIND -10, WHICH SHOULD NOT BE PRESENT");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to find nonexistent value -10!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");

        Console.WriteLine("AutoChecked: Should NOT be able to find 11?");
        if (sa.Find(11))
            Console.WriteLine("TEST FAILED: ABLE TO FIND 11, WHICH SHOULD NOT BE PRESENT");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test Passed: Unable to find nonexistent value 11!");
        Console.WriteLine("\n*******************\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What you mean, is an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, if you check array indexes.
What's your problem? Do you want to raise the execption, or do you want to catch them ? I don't see any `if idx > 4 throw something` in your code. Overflow and Underflow is something for values, that don't fit in the range of an data-type.
Like assigning 300 to a byte.

Comment: Using Pascal casing for variables is confusing, consider using camel casing i.e. `UnderflowException exception` - `Exception.Message` looks like a static property.

Comment: [An OverflowException is thrown at run time under the following conditions:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception?view=netframework-4.8) *An arithmetic operation produces a result that is outside the range of the data type returned by the operation.* and *A casting or conversion operation attempts to perform a narrowing conversion, and the value of the source data type is outside the range of the target data type.* None of those mentions the out of bounds of an array. I expect something similar for UnderflowException.

Comment: "What is wrong with my code", please don't create quizes. Please explain **why** you think there is something wrong with your code, like explaining what you expected, what actually happened, what you tried in order to figure it out, and what you learned.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET, arrays will throw a [`System.IndexOutOfRangeException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception) in both such cases, so that is what you need to check for:

```
try
{
    rgNums[idx]=val;
}
catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

There is no built-in exception for Underflow in the framework.

There is an [`OverflowException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.overflowexception), but is used for when a value goes out of the allowed range for its type, e.g. an operation of type `int` that produces a value that exceeds `Int32.MaxValue`.

If your *specification* requires Under- and Overflow exceptions, then you will have to implement these yourself as custom Exception classes, and you will need to check for the specific range violations before they occur inside your `SetAtIndex` method and then throw each corresponding exception yourself. ***Example code***:

```
public void SetAtIndex(int idx, int val)
{
    try
    {
        CheckIndex(rgNums, idx); /* NEW CODE */
        rgNums[idx] = val;
    }
    catch (UnderflowException Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
    }
    catch (OverflowException Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
    }
}

public int GetAtIndex(int idx)
{
    try
    {
        CheckIndex(rgNums, idx); /* NEW CODE */
        return rgNums[idx];
    }
    catch (UnderflowException Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
    }
    catch (OverflowException Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
    }

    return 0;
}

private void CheckIndex(int[] arr, int idx)
{
    if (idx < 0)
        throw new UnderflowException();
    if (idx >= arr.Length)
        throw new OverflowException();
}
```

combined with

```
public class UnderflowException : Exception
{
    // add what you need here, if anything...
}

public class OverflowException : Exception
{
    // add what you need here, if anything...
}
```

**Working demo:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/qJDYFt

Comment: @James And it's bad design, to use existing Exceptions just for personal use, without obeying what they are intended for. It's like throwing an ArgumentNullException when taking the root of a negative number. Just weird.

Comment: @Holger I updated the original post. I included the tests my code needs to pass. Are you able to provide any insight on how I can get my exceptions to work and pass those tests? Please and thank you.

Comment: @Holger in this case I agree, but not in general, you've used an extreme example to suit your argument. Wrapping System and/or 3rd party exceptions with your own Exception isn't "bad design" if the shoe fits e.g. wrapping a `FileNotFoundException` with a custom `SomethingFailedException` is perfectly acceptable IMO.

Comment: @RomanKudryashov You are not satisfied with this answer ? You want to implement a second time, what the system already implements ? I recommend you this answer here from Peter.B. and the other solution with Otherflow/Underflow you got from  Genotypek below.

Comment: @James. It's the general case, nothing extrem. It's about contradicting the documentation of an Exception.Maybe you are going more easy with a double meaning of words, like using the word overflow, for an index-out-of-range, but It's not. It's well defined, that an overflow is something different. And as the OP corrected his question, now he has a personal class OverflowException, not using the class System.OverflowException. Again something people can get confused with.

Comment: @Holger No, I reacted because you called this a "case". It's generally valid. It's nether bad design to create you own exceptions, but it's always bad design to use predefined exception for something else, than what they are intended for. Even more general, you should not start redefining words. Programming is not colloquial language, it's exact language. This starts with simple things like the difference from Null to Zero. It's not interchangable. As well as bad index and overflow is not.

Comment: @James. I tell you, this is not wrapping here at all. If you would wrap a class, it would be a member property of another class. You just don't take words very exact. In the same way, you probably have a different meaning of overflow in mind, than me (or Microsoft, or others).
Raising an overflow, if no overflow occurs, is just confusing to everyone. That is logic, I don't need empirical proof. It's just exact language - not  "decoupling layers". You can take the comment of Rene under the question, or the answer of Dhiray as proof. Overflows occurs on algebraic operations - nowhere else.Never

Answer (score 0):

You have to throw these exceptions manually before referencing the array.
Just validate in `try` before array operation:

```
if (idx < 0)
    throw new UnderflowException();

if (idx >= rgNums.Count())
    throw new OverflowException();
```

Comment: Where do I insert this? Into the "try block?" When I did it, it wanted me to enter the custom Exception text, but I want to use the build in one. the .Message function

Comment: @RomanKudryashov Your class has a constructor with a string, you have to pass a string. If the compiler is telling you what to do, why you just don't do it ? If you want to use the built-in exceptions you have to delete your own Exception classes. Why do you define them, if you don't want to use them ?

Comment: @Holger The UnderFlow/OverFlow Exception classes, and Program class are provided for me with this assignment. The SmartArray is the class I need to modify in order to pass the tests listed in the Program class. I am not sure how to properly use the exceptions to pass those tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wanted to do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var smartArray = new SmartArray(10);
        smartArray.SetAtIndex(100, 10);
    }
}

public class SmartArray
{
    private int[] _array;

    public SmartArray()
    {
        _array = new int[5];
    }

    public SmartArray(int length)
    {
        _array = new int[length];
    }

    public void SetAtIndex(int index, int value)
    {
        try
        {
            _array[index] = value;
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public int GetAtIndex(int index)
    {
        try
        {
            return _array[index];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway you should always handle errors instead of just ignoring them, you shouldn't catch the error in your class but handle it when you are using this object depending on the needs.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow exceptions are used when any user has stored the maximum value of the datatypes and it increases from that values. As for example,
int a=int.MaxValues ;
a++ ;
This will throw overflow exceptions. 
Underflow exceptions are just opposite to Overflow exceptions.

For throwing these exceptions , you have to configure below option in visual studio

1. Right-click your Project within the Solution Explorer.
2. Select Properties.
3. Select the Build tab along the left.
4. Select the Advanced… button.
5. Within the Advanced Build Settings dialog, check the Check for arithmetic overflow /

underflow check-box.

public void OverFlowException()
        {
            try
            {

```
            // Overflow exception
            int maxNumber = int.MaxValue;
            maxNumber++;

        }
        catch (UnderflowException Exception)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
        }
        catch (OverflowException Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

---

What you have used is different concept. In your code , if you want to throw UnderflowException , then just write below code
public Exception UnderflowException: Exception
{
}

Hope this helps to resolve the query.

Comment: I don't really think that "*opposite to Overflow exceptions*" actually exist. How would you define it? If you do `int i = int.MinValue; i--;` I believe it throws an overflow exception too